# Wordpress using P flag lead to 500

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite URL in Wordpress without changing URL in adress bar so I've tried something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fences/accessories/ category/offer/buildings/fences/accessories/ [P]
```

when I use P flag, I get 500 server error. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [P] flag implies that you have mod_proxy installed on your Apache and probably it is not the case.

Due to the fact that your are not redirecting to any external URI, but to an internal one, you don't need the [P] flag but the [L] flag should just be enough if you want to terminate there the rule processing.

Comment: [L] is not enough :( it is localhost Xampp I'll check mod_proxy then

Comment: The "problem" here is WordPress. If you simply rewrite the request then WP still sees the original URL that was requested (ie. `REQUEST_URI`). You would need to use mod_proxy, or do this entirely within WP (which is probably the "correct" way to do it).